# Finding a String in another String Using Recursion Mechanism in Core Java

Tags: java, recursion

I have the below Problem Statement

**PS: Given a string "str" and a Non-Empty substring "sub" ,compute "Recursively" if at least "N" copies of "sub" appear in the "string somewhere", possibly with "Overlapping". 
N will be non-negative.**

`Example are as shown below`
`strCopies("catcowcat", "cat", 2) → true`
`strCopies("catcowcat", "cow", 2) → false`
`strCopies("catcowcat", "cow", 1) → true`
`strCopies("iiijjj", "ii", 2) → true`

I have written the code as shown below(without recursion) and is working fine for few test cases,except for others which are marked as FAIL.

**:::Code is as shown below:::**

```
public boolean strCopies(String str, String sub, int n) {    
    int len = sub.length();    
    int result=0;    
    if(len>0){    
       int start = str.indexOf(sub);    
       while(start !=-1){    
              result++;    
              start = str.indexOf(sub,start+len);                     
       }
    }          
   if(result==n){
        return true;
   }else return false; 
}
```

Runs for above code as shown below(Marked in BOLD are FAILED TEST CASES)

`Expected This Run`
`strCopies("catcowcat", "cat", 2) → true true OK`
`strCopies("catcowcat", "cow", 2) → false false OK`
`strCopies("catcowcat", "cow", 1) → true true OK`
`strCopies("iiijjj", "ii", 2) → true false FAIL`
`strCopies("iiiiij", "iii", 3) → true false FAIL`
`strCopies("ijiiiiij", "iiii", 2) → true false FAIL`

**Could you check and let me know what is wrong with the code for FAIL TEST CASES ?Im unable to consider the Overlapping scenarios.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, your first problem is that your method isn't recursive. I suspect you want to work with `substring` as well as `indexOf`...

As for why your current method isn't working, I suspect it's because you're using `start +  len` instead of `start + 1` to find the next starting position. So when trying to find "ii" in "iii", you should first look at position 0, then position 1 - currently you're looking at position 2, which would mean it wouldn't find the second "ii" starting at 1.

Comment: what fix is required for the program in order to work for FAIL test cases.

Comment: @Deepak: I'm not just going to give you the code, as this is clearly a homework exercise (and one which has nothing to do with arrays - I'm not sure why you've tagged it that way). I've explained what's wrong with your current code, and also suggested that you should use recursion as per the instructions. If you have trouble understanding what I've written, please say so - but I'm not going to just do your homework for you. That wouldn't help anyone.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your solution is not recursive (`strCopies` does not call itself).

Here is a suggestion for a recursive version of your algorithm:

```
public static boolean strCopies(String str, String sub, int n) {
    if (str.isEmpty())
        return n == 0;
    int remainingN = str.startsWith(sub) ? n - 1 : n;
    return strCopies(str.substring(1), sub, remainingN);
}
```

[(All your test-cases pass.)](http://ideone.com/aFzDZ)

---

Btw, note that your last lines of code:

```
if(result==n)
    return true;
else
    return false;
```

can always be replaced with simply

```
return result == n;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class StackOverflow {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  String string = "catcowcat";
  String substring = "cat";
  System.out.println(string + " has " + findNumberOfStrings(string, substring, 0) + " " + substring);
 }

 private static int findNumberOfStrings(String string, String substring, int count){
  if (string.length() == 0){
   return count + 0;
  }
  if (string.length() < substring.length()){
   return count + 0;
  }
  if (string.contains(substring)){
   count++;
   string = string.replaceFirst(substring, "");
   return findNumberOfStrings(string, substring, count);
  }
  return count;
 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The pure recursion code for the problem is:

```
public boolean strCopies(String str, String sub, int n) {
   if(n==0) return true;
   if(str.length()==0) return false;
   if(str.length()<sub.length()) return false;
   if(str.startsWith(sub)) return strCount(str.substring(1),sub, n, 1);
   return strCopies(str.substring(1),sub,n);
}

public boolean strCount(String str , String sub , int n , int count ) {
   if( count>= n) return true;
   if(str.length()==0) return false;
   if(str.length()<sub.length()) return false;
   if(str.startsWith(sub)) {
   count++;
   if( count>= n) return true;
   }
   return strCount(str.substring(1),sub, n , count );
}
```

We have to maintain a count of occurrences of sub in str string. But in recursive call of strCopies function if we take count variable, everytime function is called the value of var count will reinitialize (we cannot maintain count in memory of function and cannot keep on adding to its previous value). So for maintaining the value of count we pass the value of count to another function strCount (as `return strCount(str.substring(1), sub, n, count ) )` which also works recursively and can do count++, as it is called with a value of count only and count doesnot  get reintialized  rather get carried forward.

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is that you search for the index of the sub word and then you send the new string which is starting one character after the index you have found the word since  you allow overlapping.

```
public boolean strCopies(String str, String sub, int n) {

 if (str == null || str.equals("") || str.length() < sub.length())
  if (n == 0)
    return true;
  else 
    return false;


 int index =  str.indexOf(sub);
 if (index != -1)
  return false || strCopies(str.substring(index + 1),sub,--n);
 else
  return false || strCopies("",sub,n);

}
```