# Given two Strings, determine if 1 is a substring of the other recursively

Tags: java, recursion

I'm running through some practice problems, one of which is to take two Strings and determine if one is a substring of the other. I wrote my first solution:

```
public static boolean isSubstring(String s1, String s2){
    String longer = s1.length() > s2.length() ? s1 : s2;
    String shorter = s1.length() < s2.length() ? s1 : s2;
    String substring;

    for(int i = 0; i < longer.length() && i + shorter.length() <= longer.length(); i++){
        substring = longer.substring(i, i + shorter.length());
        if(substring.equals(shorter))
          return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

And then I remembered that Java has a contains method for String class, and the solution is trivial at that point. :

```
public static boolean isSubstringUsingContains(String s1, String s2){
  String longer = s1.length() > s2.length() ? s1 : s2;
  String shorter = s1.length() < s2.length() ? s1 : s2;
  return longer.contains(shorter);

}
```

Since I'm practicing and I'm not very good at recursion, I thought I should try to solve this recursively, and I have not been able to do so correctly. How can I solve this with recursion, and are there any pros/cons for using recursion here as opposed to the above solutions. Here is my failed attempt at a recursive solution for this problem:

```
 public static boolean isSubstringRecursive(String s1, String s2,int i){
  if(s1.length() == 0 || s2.length() == 0)
   return false;

  String longer = s1.length() > s2.length() ? s1 : s2;
  String shorter = s1.length() < s2.length() ? s1 : s2;

  if(longer.equals(shorter))
     return true;

  return isSubstringRecursive(longer.substring(i,i + shorter.length()),shorter,i + 1);


}
```

**EDIT**

Test Cases:
String A = "Batman"  String B = "atm"  RESULT: True

String A = "Handstand" String B = "stand" RESULT: True

String A = "Hotsauce" String B = "ecu" RESULT: False

Comment: Do you have testcases?

Comment: recursion is a loop in diguise - there is no loop in your working code: why do you think you need a recursion?

Comment: I'd recommend having `startsWith` for your base case and `substring(1)` for your recursive case.  If the longer string starts with the shorter one, then you're finished.  Otherwise, lop off the first character and recurse.

Comment: Great answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/4530468/6328256

Comment: @DavidWallace great point

Comment: @assylias there is a loop in my first solution; and recursion is not something I need, rather it's something I need to learn how to do correctly.

Comment: @ElroyJetson Try making a recursion with something easier, like Factorial

Comment: @Jerfov2 I can do recursion for Factorial, or Fibonacci, tree traversal, etc. It's not something I'm good at, so I'm trying to practice with things that I've never done before.

Comment: @ElroyJetson It's wonderful that you're eager to learn, but I think there are other tasks that recursion would make more sense for and would help your understanding better

Comment: @Jerfov2 point taken.

Comment: @ElroyJetson [Here's](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~calvin/cs110/RECURSION.html) a good page on recursion. It gets at the core of what recursion is supposed to do: Take big problems (e.g. a tree), and break it down into smaller ones (e.g. to nodes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am making minimal changes to your routine to make it work. see my comments in the code for explanation.

```
/* Adding an extra argument to store the longest value constantly across multiple recursions. */
public static boolean isSubstringRecursive(String longString, String s1, String s2,int i){

  if(s1.length() == 0 || s2.length() == 0)
   return false;

  String longer = s1.length() >= s2.length() ? s1 : s2;
  String shorter = s1.length() < s2.length() ? s1 : s2;

  /* set the longString in the first iteration only */
  if(i==0)longString=longer;

  if(longer.equals(shorter))
     return true;

  /* To prevent substring to go out of boounds */
  if(i+ shorter.length() > longString.length()) return false;

  /* Use longString for substring since it holds the originally long string */
  return isSubstringRecursive(longString, longString.substring(i,i + shorter.length()),shorter,i + 1); 

}
```

This code can be further optimized to a great extent. But I will leave that part to you for further work.

**Note 1**: As you say, you can easily achieve this using the 'contains' method of the String class. However, in the solution that you have demonstrated for `contains`, you don't really have to check the string lengths. See the following:

`return s1.contains(s2) || s2.contains(s1);`

**Note 2**: You can also use the `indexOf` of the String class, to do the same. See the following:

`return (s1.indexOf(s2) != -1 || s2.indexOf(s1) != -1);`

Long story short, there are so many easier options to achieve your objective that there is no need to go for `recursion` option.

Comment: Thanks. It feels good that I was somewhere on the right track with the recursion. I agree that it is unneeded for a problem such as this, but thanks for taking the time out to help with my quest to improve my skillset.